# Do I need ESTA to go from Puerto Rico to Norway on a direct flight?

Tags: visas

Do I need ESTA to go from Puerto Rico with a direct flight to Norway? Will come to San Juan by boat.

Comment: What citizenship? And do you mean the ESTA 'visa-waiver' from the US? Where is the boat coming from?

Comment: Is it a cruise ship or so, or a private boat?

Comment: I thought that entering by boat was only possible with a proper visa, even for citizens from VWP countries, someone knows whether that's correct?

Comment: @Relaxed If one arrives by boat on an approved carrier, ESTA is applicable.  Visas are required for arrival on private vessels.  Despite its title, this page explains: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1132/~/citizen-of-visa-waiver-country,-wants-to-drive-into-u.s.-from-canada-or-mexico,

Answer (score 3):

No.  ESTA is applicable only for travel *to* US territory.

Answer (score 2):

You will (or might) need an ESTA to enter San Juan by boat, but not to leave San Juan by air.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a correct answer.

Comment: @CGCampbell Care to elaborate?

Answer (score -3):

As far as I am concerned, Puerto Rico is not in the US and ESTA is only required when travelling to the us... And since you sate your flight is directly to Norway ESTA is completely irrelevant. It would be like requiring a Chinese Visa to fly directly from South Korea to Belgium.

Comment: OK, “as far as [you are] concerned”, it should not be required but is it as far as the US authorities are concerned? Or as far as whoever actually mans border checkpoints in ports and airports is concerned, to put it in the most neutral way possible? Can one actually board a plane with no visa and no ESTA or is your answer just empty posturing?

Comment: @Relaxed This answer is a load of nonsense. Puerto Rico is a United States territory. It is not one of the several States, but for the purposes of entry it is no different to Washington DC; immigration control is performed by the US Customs and Border Protection. On arrival it looks just like entering any US State, and there are no border controls between Puerto Rico and the US mainland. See https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1094/~/do-i-need-to-apply-for-esta "Yes an ESTA is required"

Comment: @Relaxed (However, as I noted in my answer, the OP still does not need an ESTA because OP is leaving US territory not entering it.)